# Is this an Inner Class

Tags: java, structure, inner-classes

Can anyone explain how this code snippet works... The actual code itself is not relevant as it was from a short tutorial on using an MVP pattern for Android.

My main question is how this code structure works and whether this is an inner class, of sorts, or maybe a transaction.. I haven't seen a code structure like this in Java and I would like to undertsand it to learn from it as it seems efficient and minimal.

```
public void loadCustomer(int id) {
    (mCustomerModel.load(id)) {
        mCustomerView.setId(mCustomerModel.getId());
        mCustomerView.setFirstName(mCustomerModel.getFirstName());
        mCustomerView.setLastName(mCustomerModel.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more of organisation style, you can perfectly skip the curly brackets.

Comment: its the three method calls inside another method call that is confusing me... inside a set of brackets from the first method call. Am I being dumb... :-)

Comment: @leeb898 no `;` after `(mCustomerModel.load(id))` ?

Comment: @assylias yes its the curly brackets that confused me. Is it ocrrect to say that they are nothing more than a containing block of code and not acting like some sort of inner class?

Comment: @leeb898 IMO this does not compile - but I might be missing something.

Comment: Are you sure the tutorial didn't just forget an `if`?

Comment: Does this code compile? I don't think a method call on its own (without a `;`) is valid Java syntax.

Comment: The source: http://magenic.com/Blog/AnMVPPatternforAndroid

Comment: You're not going crazy: The article has a typo (and should likely have an `if` statement prior to the `load` call.) With the `if`, the code just says "If the load in the model succeeds, update the UI."

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is straight forward, but certainly appears slightly unusual.  The round brackets surrounding mCustomerModel.load(id) are superfluous, and in this case the curly braces around the next three lines are also superfluous.  In a another case, if a local variable had been declared within that block, it's scope would be limited to that block only.  The code below is equivalent:

```
public void loadCustomer(int id) {
    mCustomerModel.load(id);
    mCustomerView.setId(mCustomerModel.getId());
    mCustomerView.setFirstName(mCustomerModel.getFirstName());
    mCustomerView.setLastName(mCustomerModel.getLastName());

}
```

EDIT:  Missed the intention that the line within round brackets should be an if statement.  That being the case, the code is fairly self explanatory once "if" has been added.

Comment: This does not compile (missing `;`)

Comment: If you feel like you misinterpreted the question, you can simply delete your answer (link below the answer).

Comment: @Monty Goodepuppee I understand now, with the If statement makes normal sense and without it is just organisational structure to the the method calls.